# how can I make a page break using itext

Tags: java, itext

I want to generate a pdf using itext. I would at some point while the content was added to make a page break. I need to insert several separate conenidos dependence origin so I ask the user to do so on separate pages. Any ideas???

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Anyone looking for a solution in iText7, please use the solution from @BadLeo, which is to use `document.add(new AreaBreak());`

***Below answer is applicable for versions prior to 7.***

Calling `document.newPage()` tells iText to place subsequent objects on a new page. The new page will only actually get created when you place the next object. Also, `newPage()` only creates a new page if the current page is not blank; otherwise, it's ignored; you can use `setPageBlank(false)` to overcome that.

Refer below link for an example:
http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=99 (Edit: dead 404)

Since the above link is dead, adding example code for anyone who is till using version prior to iText7.

```
/**
 * Creates from the given Collection of images an pdf file.
 *
 * @param result
 *            the output stream from the pdf file where the images shell be written.
 * @param images
 *            the BufferedImage collection to be written in the pdf file.
 * @throws DocumentException
 *             is thrown if an error occurs when trying to get an instance of {@link PdfWriter}.
 * @throws IOException
 *             Signals that an I/O exception has occurred.
 */
public static void createPdf(final OutputStream result, final List<BufferedImage> images)
  throws DocumentException, IOException
{
  final Document document = new Document();
  PdfWriter.getInstance(document, result);
  for (final BufferedImage image : images)
  {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
    final Image img = Image.getInstance(baos.toByteArray());
    document.setPageSize(img);
    document.setPageBlank(false);
    document.newPage();
    img.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
    document.add(img);
  }
  document.close();
}
```

Comment: After adding the page, you need to create a new PDPageContentStream for the new page to have the content go to the right place....

Comment: Why posing dead link instead of pasting some code?

Answer (score 21):

For iText7 try:

```
document.add(new AreaBreak());
```

Source: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.0.0/com/itextpdf/layout/element/AreaBreak.html

Comment: this actually works like a charm. calling document.newPage() only add a new blank page, but any new object that supposed to be appended on the new page are still appended on the 1st page. Objects are overlapping each other on the first page, while others are blank.

Comment: @andre_northwind You need to make a new contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page); for the new page.

Answer (score 2):

in itext 7, try:

outside loop:

```
pdfDocument.addNewPage();
```

inside loop:

```
document.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
```