# I want to render data column wise in table in itext 7.0.1

Tags: java, pdf, arraylist, itext

Generally in table cells go row wise but I want to render it column wise.
Data is stored in an array list.

`-----------` means page break

Expectation is:

```
1  6
2  7
3  8        
4  9
5  10
-------------
11  16
12  17
13  18
```

But generally it comes like this

```
1  2
3  4
5  6
7  8
9  10
-------------
11  12
13  14
15  16
17  18
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the renderer to a `ColumnDocumentRenderer` as described in the tutorial: https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2

Comment: Try this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198337/how-can-i-make-a-page-break-using-itext

Comment: @BrunoLowagie more requirements are there like, a header and footer(page no.) on every page of pdf. whent i tried to add header it was rendered on every column.

Comment: Headers and footers should be added using an event handler, e.g. when a new page starts. Is that how you did it?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I tried this code https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/examples/chapter-2#1903-c02e13_jekyllhydev9.java for page number footer and kept immediate flush false still getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary.get(PdfDictionary.java:456)"

Comment: You need to read the full tutorial. I advised you to us ab event handler: https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/examples/chapter-7

Comment: Thanks @Bruno for your help, able to achieve requirements

Comment: @BrunoLowagie In above example rectangles height is fixed, suppose i have to use default renderer for some data(list_A) wherever it ends, need to switch renderer to ColumnDocumentRenderer for another data(list_B) then wherever it ends again need to switch to default renderer. So here how can I set the height of rectangles? If first condition ends somewhere in between the page then for that page height should be different and for next according to remaining height should be diffrent.